# A function that returns the highest average from multiple lists of numbers

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, average

I have to define a `highestAverage :: [[Int]] -> Double` function that returns the highest average from a list of lists containing numbers.

For example:

`bestAverage [[3,1], [5,4,3], [], [5,5,5], [1,2,3]] == 5.0`

I have already written a function that returns the average of a list.

```
listAverage :: [Int] -> Double
listAverage [] = 0.0
listAverage x = fromIntegral(sum x)/fromIntegral(length x)
```

My problem is that I can't figure out a way to have it do recursion. I always get errors when loading in my module.
My code right now looks like this:

```
highestAverage :: [[Int]] -> Double
highestAverage [[]] = 0.0
highestAverage (x:xs) = max(listAverage x, listAverage xs)
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Are `listAverage` and `groupAvg` supposed to be the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a non-empty list you call the `groupAvg` on the first sublist `x`, and then determine the `max` between that value, and the recursive call on the tail of the list. The base case is a single sublist where we calculate the maxiumum:

```
highestAverage :: [[Int]] -> Double
highestAverage [x] = listAverage x
highestAverage (x:xs) = max (listAverage x) (highestAverage xs)
```

This function will *not* work for an empty list. If you want to return `0` for an empty list, you can alter the base case to:

```
highestAverage :: [[Int]] -> Double
highestAverage [] = 0
highestAverage (x:xs) = max (listAverage x) (highestAverage xs)
```

Comment: the second version won't work if some sublists lists may have negative averages - if ALL do, this will incorrectly give 0 for the highest average.

Comment: @RobinZigmond: yes, I'm not a fan of this either, normally a maximum on an empty list should not return anything, since it makes no sense. But the average of an empty list should not return `0` either.

Comment: If you're going to hard-code a result for the empty list, it should better be `-1/0` in Float, or `minBound` in integer. But I agree that it's better to leave the maximum of an empty list as undefined or `Nothing`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply map your function over the list and take the maximum:

maximum $ map listAverage [[3,1], [5,4,3], [], [5,5,5], [1,2,3]]